Residue theorem and Cauchy integral formula with fractional powers
I am trying to understand what is the interaction between fractional powers and contour integration.
For example, I believe that if $f$ is an entire function and $p$ a natural integer, by the residue theorem
$$
\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-x} z^{-p} \text dz = \sum_{k=p}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^{k-p},
$$
where $\gamma$ is a contour that enclose the interval $[0, x]$.
So everything behave nicely when $p$ is an integer. But what happens when $p$ is a complex number? $p=1/2$?
